# Image index of TreeView node changes upon selection

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, imagelist

When I tried using the imagelist in treeview, the image index changes when treenode is clicked. I have no idea why it is happening. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

You need to set both the ImageIndex and the SelectedImageIndex on the tree node.

Answer (score 10):

'SelectedImageIndex's intent is to allow displaying a different image upon selection than what is set by the 'ImageIndex' for a particular node.  To keep these two consistent it is necessary to set them to the same value. This can be done at design time or programmatically depending on your needs.

For example, if the images never change then it is as simple as setting them concurrently when a new node is added to the TreeView:

```
int myCurrentImageIndex = 0;
TreeNode node = myTreeView.Nodes.Add("new node!");
node.ImageIndex = node.SelectedImageIndex = myCurrentImageIndex;
```

However, if you do change the ImageIndex value for any reason after its initial creation (such as a response to some kind of user action), then you must also change the SelectedImageIndex as well.  Otherwise, they will become inconsistent.

```
int myNewImageIndex = 1;
node.ImageIndex = node.SelectedImageIndex = myNewImageIndex;
```

(Note it is not enough to set them to be the same in the event handler of the 'AfterSelect' event.  It must be done anywhere in your code where ImageIndex changes.)

Comment: If you're doing an application that presents its structure like a folder, your users will appreciate having the change in image when they've selected a "folder."  Just make sure the change isn't too garish or subtle.

Comment: Ok, I have the same situation. But how do I completely stop this behavior? All my nodes are created during runtime. Tracking the AfterSelect event will give me a way to stop this?

Comment: I had the exact situation as well. What I did was create a static dictionary to house the images with an associated index because I was not able to determine the index of the imagelist at run time since they were added dynamically. So I used something such as: public static readonly Dictionary<string, int> TREEVIEW_ICONS = new Dictionary<string, int>(); and maintained it on add. The string in the dictionary was the unique file name of the image and the int was my way of tracking the index. I.e. TREEVIEW_ICONS.Add(iconFileName, TREEVIEW_ICONS.Count)

Answer (score 1):

you can directly do it in the constructor :

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode("My treenode", 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
tn.Text = "NewRecord";
tn.ImageIndex = 1;

treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(tn);
treeView.SelectedNode = tn;
treeView.SelectedNode.SelectedImageIndex = tn.ImageIndex; // <--- Problem solved
tn.BeginEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this line:

`Node.SelectedIndex:=Node.ImageIndex;`